# Android - Cannot send DatagramPacket

Tags: java, android, multithreading, udp

I'm building a program that will send/receive data between two android devices.
First i created a client thread to send data

```
public void run() {
    try {   

        //Create the datagram packet
        byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, addr, 5555);


        //Create Datagram Socket

        DatagramSocket socket =  new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setBroadcast(broadcast);

        // send the packet
        socket.send(packet); // i think that the problem was here



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("CTHREAD", "erreur");
    }
```

At the Server thread, i want to receive this packet, so i opened a datagramsocket to receive ten the packet.

```
 public void run() {
            try {

                  serverIP = getLocalIpAddress();  
                  Log.v("addr", serverIP);        
                  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5001); 
                  Log.v("socket", "created");


                  while(socketOk) { //boucle infini                  
                         Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                        // Log.v("client", "received");
                         try {

                            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(5556);
                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; //buffer
                            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length); 
                            socket.receive(packet);
                            byte[] result = new byte[packet.getLength()];
                            System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), 0, result, 0, packet.getLength());
                            String msg = new String(result);
                            updateGui(msg, packet.getAddress());


                         } catch (Exception e) {
                             socketOk =false;
                             Log.v("ServerThread", "SocketOk =false");

                         }
                     }
                  } 
                catch (Exception e) {}
        }
}
```

When i want to send a message, i obtain some warning so the program can't run the ClientThread.

```
at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:284)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

So, how what's is the problem??? And how can i can fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending to port 5555 but you're receiving on port 5556.

You'd be better off keeping the server's DatagramSocket open for the life of the process.